# Is it possible to make content within a TD element editable with CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I know I can place a DIV tag where I want content to be editable. But I'd like to avoid using DIV if possible. We are using CKEditor to fashion an HTML template system.

We have meticulously edited some of our templates to play nice across all browsers, but particularly Outlook 03, 07 and 2010. So ultimately we want to preserve the structure of our templates but allow content editors to easily add/edit content within tables. Tables are widely known to be the best practice when creating HTML newsletters, again - particularly when it comes to MS OUtlook.

Plenty of searching before asking this, but I couldn't find anything that specifically addresses how CKEditor plays with Table elements.